# How can i add the offset with window.location.hash

Tags: jquery, html, hash

I use this function.

```
window.location.hash = "Home"
```

What i want to do is, that when the anchor goes to the div with the id Home i wanted to have the top position of the a bit higher than the div acctually starts.

Can anybody help me to add an offset for example 20px where the div starts.

Thanks

Comment: What's the relation between `window.location.hash` and `<div>` position?

Comment: Cannot you add some padding to the DIV instead?

Comment: with the function window.location.hash i can jump to the div with the id Home with jquery, but what i want is that i jump to the div with a gap between the top border of the browser and the div. I can't use a padding, because i make a one page design template

Answer (score 2):

You can try offsetTop

A simple example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"]').bind('click.smoothscroll',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
      
        var target = this.hash,
        $target = $(target);
      
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top-40
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});
```

Note the `$target.offset().top-40`

this means that it will redirect to the div with `margin-top: -40px`.

Comment: Maybe you could bind it to onhashchange event too, depending what OP is looking for. Anyway, +1

Comment: I'm just showing a very basic example. We don't see the whole code from OP so this basic example should be enough.

Comment: Ya, i'm completly agree

Comment: that demo is exactally what i use, but what i also use is, how to change the anchors if i just scroll down ?

Comment: What do you mean? can you post your whole piece of code?

Comment: we can use the code of the demo link, there if i scroll down, in the url nothing happens. What i acctually need is that if i scroll down, the url adds the anchors (#one, #two or #three)